# OpenCV VideoWriter doesn't work

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use opencv videoWriter to get a video file. But I get the following problem:

```
>[libx264 @ 0x132b680] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
>[libx264 @ 0x132b680] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
>[libx264 @ 0x132b680] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
>[libx264 @ 0x132b680] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
>[libx264 @ 0x132b680] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
>Could not open codec 'libx264': Unspecified error!!! Output video could not be opened
```

I do have libx264 in my system, so I guess this last line is just a side effect
The code i'm trying to run is an example taken from [How to write video file in OpenCV 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623394/how-to-write-video-file-in-opencv-2-4-3) .

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
// Load input video
VideoCapture input_cap("testi.mp4");
if (!input_cap.isOpened())
{
        std::cout << "!!! Input video could not be opened" << std::endl;
        return -1;
}

// Setup output video
cv::VideoWriter output_cap("testo.mp4", 
               input_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
               input_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
               cv::Size(input_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
               input_cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));

if (!output_cap.isOpened())
{
        std::cout << "!!! Output video could not be opened" << std::endl;
        return -1;
}


// Loop to read from input and write to output
cv::Mat frame;

while (true)
{       
    if (!input_cap.read(frame))             
        break;

    output_cap.write(frame);
}

input_cap.release();
output_cap.release();

return 0;
}
```

I found a post with a similar problem [How to get stream info from opened file in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730514/how-to-get-stream-info-from-opened-file-in-ffmpeg) but no one answered correctly yet.
I've found people are told to check if opencv is using old fmmpeg instead of libav, which it isn't since it's a fresh build and my ubuntu doesn't have ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimazavr's answer is not totally right. First, you need to change the output video filename extension from `.mp4` to `.avi`. Then if you run the code, you will get the following error information:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/rwduzhao/store/opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1372
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/rwduzhao/store/opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1372: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Aborted (core dumped)
```

That means either `cv::VideoWriter` in `opencv2.4` doesn't support `libx264` format or `avi` extension is not incompatible with `libx264` format. I suggest not to use `libx264` codec. You can try the following codec formats list supported by `CV_FOURCC`:

```
CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')    = MPEG-1 codec
CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')    = motion-jpeg codec
CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2') = MPEG-4.2 codec
CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3') = MPEG-4.3 codec
CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X') = MPEG-4 codec
CV_FOURCC('U', '2', '6', '3') = H263 codec
CV_FOURCC('I', '2', '6', '3') = H263I codec
CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1') = FLV1 codec
```

From my experiences, the quality of `CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')` is fine. Besides, if you set `cv_fourcc` as `-1`, you can choose one of codec formats supported in your system in a GUI window. You can witness the running process [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpBwHxsl1_0).

Answer (score 1):

VideoWriter do not support .mp4 extension. Use .avi instead